# How to manage deployment process in IBM Watson Assistant when multiple developers are involved?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

We have separate skills for each environment dev, qa, prod. We use the v1 API, i.e., we don't have an assistant. Whenever development is completed in dev skill, we export and import in qa skill.

Recently, we faced issues when some issue happens in qa and we need to fix it in dev skill. We had 2 options:

1. Loose the ongoing development process and take up qa skill.
2. Make the fix in dev and manually do those changes in qa skill.

Is there a better way to handle these scenarios? I have checked using v2 + assistant i.e., using one skill multiple assistants but even then we will face this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually" apply the changes? In the UI or to the JSON file?

Comment: @data_henrik in the UI..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you always [download the skill as JSON file](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-backup). If you use a version control system, then this file should be managed in there.

You can **diff** the changes, edit the skill in an editor, find / replace names, etc. Thus, you could apply the fixes from dev to qa.

The JSON file with the skill can even contain training data such as counterexamples. The skill file is independent of the API version (v1 / v2).

**Update**: Here is the official IBM Watson Assistant [recommendation on the development process](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dev-process).

Comment: Lets say we bring JSON also into version control. If dev has 2 use cases, but only one should be moved to qa..in that scenario how do we find the differences to be picked up. sorry if it seems to be a very basic question.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at the exported skill. Here is one from the tutorials, nicely formatted: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/slack-chatbot-database-watson/blob/master/skill-TutorialSlackbot.json There a diff tools for JSON which you could apply to your snapshots

Comment: I added a link to the docs where they explain the development process